# Expose API and authenticate using CA signed certificate

Tags: api

I want to expose an API to other system and process the request (Json format) in Salesforce.

I don't want to use Rest architecture.

How can I achieve this. What Url the other system will hit to send the request.

Authentication will be via certificates.

Comment: You want to receive a JSON payload but you don't want to use REST? How exactly are you going to expose a web based API without handling standard HTTP verbs? The only other commonly supported API by Salesforce is SOAP based, which doesn't work with JSON payloads.

Comment: Are you just going to send the request to a Visualforce page and process the JSON in the controller? If that was the case then you would use the URL of the Visualforce page.